# Cabal update error: "ErrorMisc Unsuccessful HTTP code: 404"

Tags: haskell, cabal, http-error, cabal-install

I have a problem with a fresh installation of the Haskell-Platform 2013.2. When I want to run `cabal update` I get the error as aforementioned. I have no idea what is going wrong.

Meiner

Comment: Could you post the whole output you get when running `cabal update -v2`?

Comment: `Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: Failed to download
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz : ErrorMisc
"Unsucessful HTTP code: 404"`

Comment: Have you tried accessing the given url (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz) in a browser? Does that work?

Comment: Yes, that works, but the access time is very long. Sometimes I get another error message: `cabal: <socket: 300>: invalid argument`.

Comment: When I try `wget  http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz` everything works. But why is cabal not working?

Comment: I found the error. Cabal doesnt seem to work with the tool "Threatfire". When the service is disabled everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem, and found this on SO on my searches.
I installed haskell to C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2014.2.0.0.
On running cabal update, I got

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal.exe: Failed to download
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz : ErrorMisc "Error
HTTP code: 404"
```

I tried powershell with admin and all of

```
cabal update
cabal install cabal-install
cabal install ghc-mod
```

all seem to do the appropriate thing